# Import own data to Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

is there a way for me to import my own data from a csv file or by using pine script or any widget from tradingview. the reason behind this is a local stock which is not on tradingview, i got the OHLC data on a csv file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `request.seed()`

> To further expand the horizons of possible data one can analyze on
> TradingView, we have Pine Seeds, which allows users to supply custom
> user-maintained EOD data feeds via GitHub for use on TradingView
> charts and within Pine Script™ code.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#request-seed